# Can Node.JS be used to validate a license key in a secure server side environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I want to develop a JS app but I want to give my users a license key they use in a config file. So my app (hosted on my server) loads up, does a request to grab a JSON config file from the organization that has bought our app, and then sends a license key from the config file to my node.js server.

then the node.js server can validate that key in a number of ways and return some indication to the JS app on whether the user is authorized to keep using the app or not.

Is this a valid use case for NodeJS??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what would prevent users from modifying the Javascript to not perform the validation?

Comment: JAB points out the potential fly in the ointment, although there are some impressive obfuscation tools which could probably reduce this risk. To the OP - you would probably be better off having some other (essential) functionality reside in the server, even if not logically needed on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it, but just like most other licensing systems is has potential to be avoided. In the case of node, it will probably be easier (due to code visibility by default) and would require additional thought as to how to prevent this.